# How do I count and enumerate the keys in an lmdb with python?

Tags: python, lmdb

```
import lmdb
env = lmdb.open(path_to_lmdb)
```

Now I seem to need to create a transaction and a cursor, but how do I get a list of keys that I can iterate over?

Comment: I spotted an extra parenthesis there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A way to get the total number of keys without enumerating them individually, counting also all sub databases:

```
with env.begin() as txn:
    length = txn.stat()['entries']
```

Test result with a hand-made database of size 1000000 on my laptop:

- the method above is instantaneous (0.0 s)
- the iteration method takes about 1 second.

Answer (score 9):

Are you looking for something like [`this`](https://lmdb.readthedocs.org/en/release/#resource-management):

```
with env.begin() as txn:
    with txn.cursor() as curs:
        # do stuff
        print 'key is:', curs.get('key')
```

### Update:

This may not be the *fastest*:

```
with env.begin() as txn:
   myList = [ key for key, _ in txn.cursor() ]
   print(myList)
```

**Disclaimer:** I don't know anything about the library, just searched its docs and searched for `key` in the docs.

Comment: No.  I'm aware of the documentation page.  I want to know how to get the total number of keys without enumerating them individually.  I would also like to know the best (fastest) way to enumerate all the key value pairs.  The method you mentioned seems to take quite a while for me, but it could have something to do with the size of my db (about 1m entries).

Comment: @Doug I updated my answer to get the list of keys, by iterating the cursor. There might be a faster way though.

Comment: Apart from the fact that it would take a long time to iterate through the keys, are there any other disadvantages to reading a list of keys?

Answer (score 4):

As Sait pointed out, you can iterate over a cursor to collect all keys. However, this may be a bit inefficient, as it would also load the values. This can be avoided, by using on the `cursor.iternext()` function with `values=False`.

```py
with env.begin() as txn:
  keys = list(txn.cursor().iternext(values=False))
```

I did a short benchmark between both methods for a DB with 2^20 entries, each with a 16 B key and 1024 B value.

Retrieving keys by iterating over the cursor (including values) took **874 ms** in average for 7 runs, while the second method, where only the keys are returned took **517 ms**. These results may differ depending on the size of keys and values.